# Remote Debugging and deployment of a Project Built Locally

Tags: git, deployment

We work on our projects locally, and deploy them on remote servers for testing. This is currently done via git commits/push/pulls. But the problem here is that most of the commit contain errors and/or break the code in significant manner due to the lack of testing.

Is there a way we can deploy the code on the remote server without using git commits, or some sort of temporary commits or patch or any other mechanism? And only commit, whenever it is important.

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** encourage commiting often, not discouraging it.

You should have several branches in your git server, at least dev/staging/production to handle that situation. Google 'development workflow' and you'll find several examples.

Finally you should look at CI servers, like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: Thanks @mvillar while I understand this, the only issue i am facing is whether it is fine to have commits where 80% of the commits are fixes like syntax errors or other petty mistakes?

Comment: Of course, there will be syntax errors, lots of fixes, etc in dev. If that weren't the case we would only have production branches and have tons of free time ;)

Comment: Haha, but is it fine to have 'em on commits? And also have commits which just adds a semi colon for an instance?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. When you and your team will be accustomed to commit often, you'll have sometimes commits adding comments, commits adding a blank space to correct indentation... etc. and that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)!

E.g.

Create a **develop** branch where you and your team usually works in, that can contain bugs, even unfinished code.

Then create a **release** branch from the **develop** branch. Now you can commit code into that branch to get the software into a stable state so that testers can work with it. Of course it's not allowed to merge the develop branch into the release branch once again.

As soon as your software in the release branch is stable and thoroughly tested, merge the **release** branch into the **master** branch and then back into the **develop** branch. After that, just delete the release branch.

Following this workflow...

- the **master** branch will only contain stable and tested code. Yay :)
- the **release** branch won't suffer from breaks the devs introduce in the develop branch during the lifetime of the release branch
- the **develop** branch will profit from stabilizing work that was done in the release branch. In fact, you should merge the release branch into the develop branch (not the other way!) as often as possible.

Comment: Thanks Sandro, we are going through the same cycles. My point of concerns is that a commit is unnecessarily broken into 4-5 commits where the tail commits solve useless issues like syntax error, etc. This makes the task of reviewing commits, etc. a bit complicated. If that is the general way though, we are close to what everyone else is doing :)

Comment: How do you split a commit in 4-5 commits?

Comment: What happens is, you code something locally. You push it, and realize that you did a stupid mistake. You commit and push again. And voila, another mistake. You do this 2-3 times more unless your api end point works properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Abhishek this sounds like a human problem,** not a git problem. Your coders need to test their work before committing. Shame is a pretty good tool here, used with humor. Loud shouts of "who broke the build?", emails, informal rules that the last one to break the build buys lunch... you figure out what works in your shop to get a habit of testing before committing.

Comment: Haha, +1 for the pinch of humor. The issue is our environment is pretty complex so we didn't set up any local environment to test things. We can write unit tests but it may take some time.